# Как скрыть сквозную ссылку после клика и не показывать до перезагрузки браузера?

Tags: javascript, сессия, localstorage

В общем есть ссылка в виде картинки, по клику на которую мы переходим на нужную страницу, ссылка должна скрываться и больше не показываться в текущей сессии.

```
<div class="help-your-dog">
    <a href="https://goodhands.vet/kak-podgotovit-sobaku-k-priemu-v-vetklinike/"
       class="help-your-dog__link help-your-dog__link--s" target="_blank">
        <img src="/upload/help_dog.png" alt="help-dog">
    </a>
</div>
```

Пробовал сделать через localStorage, но не совсем понимаю как привязать это к переходу по ссылке, застрял..

```
const dogClose = document.querySelector(".help-your-dog__close");
    function updateStorage() {
      dogBox.classList.add('hidden');
    }

    dogBox.onclick = () => {
      updateStorage();

      let dogBoxChecked = dogBox.classList.contains('hidden');

      localStorage.setItem('server', dogBoxChecked);

      if(localStorage.getItem("server") === 'true') {
        dogBox.classList.add('hidden');
      }
    }

    window.onstorage = () => {
      updateStorage();
    }
```

Comment: Вешаете обработчик события нажатия на ссылку, при клике записываете в сторадж инфу, что кликнули. При показе страницы, после загрузки, лезете в хранилище и проверяете, нажата ли ссылка или нет. Если да, скрываете. Сейчас вы все это пытаетесь сделкать в рамках одной функции. Надо разнести логику

Comment: _"... не показываться в текущей сессии."_ Тут надо бы определиться с понятием сессии, ибо `localStorage !== sessionStorage`. Новая сессия создаётся не только при перезапуске браузера, но и при открытии той же страницы в новой вкладке или в новом окне, а также при восстановлении вкладки из истории.

Comment: Объект localStorage доступен всем окнам из одного источника, поэтому, если мы устанавливаем данные в одном окне, изменения становятся видимыми в другом.

Answer (score 0):

```
  dogBox.onclick = () => {
    localStorage.setItem('server', true);
  }

  if(localStorage.getItem("server") === 'true') {
    dogBox.classList.add('hidden');
  }
```

Немного покопавшись нашел ответ